# "TypeError: must be str or None, not list" when trying to pass row from csv.reader to str.split

Tags: python, string, split

Question:

> The 10-th column of this file is 'DeathCity'. For each record in this CSV file, output the record if the city in the DeathCity column matches the user's input. Use upper() to find the match without issues of different capitalization.

```python
import csv

city = input("Enter a city name:")

f = open("/file.txt")
spamreader=csv.reader(f)

for DeathCity in spamreader:
    print("\t".split(DeathCity))
```

I keep getting an error when attempting to filter the data based on my input.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "hmwk3_1", line 7, in <module>
        print("\t".split(DeathCity))
TypeError: must be str or None, not list
```

Comment: What do you think your code currently does / what it should currently do?

Comment: My code now is just printing the entire dataset. I am wanting to filter the dataset based on my input.

Comment: `DeathCity` is a list. You can't split a list.

Comment: Did you mean `print(DeathCity)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for `csv.reader`, you will see that you are iterating over rows that are lists of strings. Each element of that list is a column, so use a subscript to access a specific column. That is the string you should compare to the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

```
for DeathCity in spamreader:
    print("\t".join(DeathCity))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you mix strings and variables in a print statement, you have to use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), or equivalent. ex) `print(f"My name is {variableToPrint}")`

Also, the "[split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)" function takes no parameters, but is dot-operated on the item you're wanting to split. ex) `DeathCity.split()`

So, to fix those two errors, try the following line of code and see if it improves anything.

```
print(f"\t{DeathCity.split()}")
```

Comment: The `split` method does take arguments, they are optional.

Comment: `TypeError: must be str or None, not list` implies that `DeathCity` is of type `list`, not `str`.